# Issue when trying to connect to SignalR

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, push-notification, signalr

I try to implement SignalR using Angular so I follow this [tutorial](http://mahedee.net/a-signalr-application-for-real-time-notification-using-angularjs-and-toastr/). In my app.js I have something like this:

```
 var app = angular.module('portalTransporte', ['common.core', 'common.ui'])
        .config(config)
        .run(run)

    $(function () {
        $.connection.hub.logging = true;
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });


    $.connection.hub.error(function (err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err);
    });

    angular.module('portalTransporte')
       .value('notification', $.connection.notification)
       .value('toastr', toastr);

/* Setup global settings */
    app.factory('settings', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        // supported languages
        var settings = {
            layout: {
                pageSidebarClosed: false, // sidebar menu state
                pageContentWhite: true, // set page content layout
                pageBodySolid: false, // solid body color state
                pageAutoScrollOnLoad: 1000 // auto scroll to top on page load
            },
            assetsPath: '../Metronic',
            globalPath: '../Metronic/global',
            layoutPath: '../Metronic/layouts/layout',
            origen: 'Web',
            version: '0.1W'
        };
        $rootScope.settings = settings;

        return settings;
    }]);

    config.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'cfpLoadingBarProvider'];
    function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        //console.log("config");
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false;
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeBar = true;
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.loadingBarTemplate = '<div id="loading-bar"><div class="bar"><div class="peg"></div></div></div>';
        //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard.html");
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
            var $state = $injector.get("$state");
            $state.go("root.dashboard");
        });

        $stateProvider
    .state('root.cliente_viaje_solicitud_detalle', {
                url: "viajes_c/solicitud/detalle.html",
                templateUrl: "../SPA/viajes_clientes/solicituddetalleCliente.html",
                controller: "solicituddetalleClienteCtrl",
                authenticate: true,
                data: { pageTitle: 'FLETERISTAS - DETALLE DE SOLICITUD' },
                params: {
                    modo: "nuevo",
                    viajeId: null
                }
```

and in JS I call function like this:

```
solicituddetalleClienteCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'apiService', 'notificationService', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', '$stateParams', '$state', 'limitToFilter', 'notification', 'toastr'];

    function solicituddetalleClienteCtrl($scope, apiService, notificationService, $rootScope, $location, $http, $stateParams, $state, limitToFilter, notification, toastr) {
$scope.guardar = function () {
            var inputval = "NewvTrip added";
            notification.server.pushNotification(inputval);
            $scope.newMessage = "";
        };

 notification.client.response = function onNewMessage(message) {
            displayMessage(message);
            $scope.$apply();
        };

        function displayMessage(message) {
            toastr.success(message); //To nofiy as fadin and fadout
        }
```

I debbug it into chrome and when It reach this line  `notification.server.pushNotification(inputval);` it always throw me

> SignalR: Connection must be started before data can be sent. Call
>   .start() before .send()

Can someone help? Regards . I can share my desktop via Skype or Chrome remote

[image]

I don´t see anything wrong when I call hub. But I prety sure problem is into app.js, I see related questions, but I didn´t find solution.

Comment: Did you see in debugger das    $.connection.hub.start(); is called before you call the method on the server?

Comment: When I open my view  solicituddetallecliente app.js dissapear from js scripts in sources using chrome console for no reason and I dont know why @Tester

Comment: Without debuging you can't work.. First you should find a solution that you can debug. After that I think you will find the mistake fastl by yourself...

Comment: Your `portalTransporte` module is very confusing. Where is the `run` function? Why are you wrapping the `start()` in the jQuery `ready` function? Maybe it's missing this part of the code but I don't see where you connect the `start` of the hub with the rest of the app. Also remember that the `start` method takes a promise and you should put  your calls to the hub inside so you know the connection it's open for sure. Also, it's unrelated to this problem but read the second note here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client